# Get shared calendars from Office 365 API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

So, here is the problem. I searched all over the MSDN and here on Stack but there isn't one definitive answer how to get (or is it even possible as of today?) to access Shared calendars in Office365.

I followed [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/authenticate-and-use-services) tutorial and here is offending method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        List<MyCalendar> myCalendars = new List<MyCalendar>();

        var signInUserId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        var userObjectId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(SettingsHelper.Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signInUserId));

        try
        {
            DiscoveryClient discClient = new DiscoveryClient(SettingsHelper.DiscoveryServiceEndpointUri,
                async () =>
                {
                    var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(SettingsHelper.DiscoveryServiceResourceId, new ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId, SettingsHelper.AppKey), new UserIdentifier(userObjectId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

                    return authResult.AccessToken;
                });

            var discoveryCapabilitiesResult = await discClient.DiscoverCapabilitiesAsync();

            var dcr = await discClient.DiscoverCapabilityAsync("Calendar");

            OutlookServicesClient exClient = new OutlookServicesClient(dcr.ServiceEndpointUri,
                async () =>
                {
                    var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(dcr.ServiceResourceId, new ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId, SettingsHelper.AppKey), new UserIdentifier(userObjectId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

                    return authResult.AccessToken;
                });

            //var calendarsResult = await exClient.Me.Calendars.ExecuteAsync();

            var calendarsResult = await exClient.Me.Calendars.ExecuteAsync();


            do
            {
                var calendars = calendarsResult.CurrentPage;
                foreach (var c in calendars)
                {
                    myCalendars.Add(new MyCalendar { DisplayName = c.Name });
                }

                calendarsResult = await calendarsResult.GetNextPageAsync();

            } while (calendarsResult != null);
        }
        catch (AdalException exception)
        {
            //handle token acquisition failure
            if (exception.ErrorCode == AdalError.FailedToAcquireTokenSilently)
            {
                authContext.TokenCache.Clear();

                //handle token acquisition failure
            }
        }

        return View(myCalendars);
    }
```

This function will return only Calendar under "My Calendars" but not the others (see the picture)

[image: Multiple calendars]

I get only the first one - that is mine calendar. Second one under "My Calendars" is shared with me (I'm not the author, somebody else is and I have r/w on it) and one under "Shared Calendars" is company-wide one (on this one I also have r/w permissions).

Is there a way to get all of them? On portal.azure.com my app is added and I set permissions for both mine and shared calendars:

[image: Permissions]

I have no idea what to do. Contacts are working properly but I cannot find a way to get any shared calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the test, the Microsoft Graph could get the all calendars. Here is the rest for your reference:

Shared calendar from chenchenLi to NanYu:
[image]

Query the calendars from NanYu:[image]

More detail about the Microsoft Graph REST to get the calendars, you can refer the link below:

[List calendars](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list_calendars)

Comment: Hi, I tested this but no luck - I'm still getting only one calendar but not other (shared) calendars (from my first post). http://imgur.com/a/k7BuA

Comment: How did you share the calendar? I shared the calendar using the button **share** on the [outlook portal](https://outlook.office365.com/) and after the user accepts, the Microsoft Graph list the calendar successfully.

Comment: Calendars are shared by our Office365 admin company-wide. Every employee has r/w permissions on it but i cannot see it over here on Graph API. It's added from Global Address book. Can you test with calendars shared by other people, where you aren't the author?

Comment: @nighthawk I also tested that shared the calendars from other, however the REST still works for me. I will update the post to upload a figure show the operation.  Is it different from you?

Comment: We managed to get shared calendars using EWS - so I guess the problem is only related to Graph API. If you can write something step-by step, it would be nice, so we can compare what we did wrong.

Comment: @nighthawk I just login the `https://outlook.office.com/owa/`(account1) and share the calendar as the figures in the post to another user(account2). Then I accept the calendar using the account2 and query the calendars using account 2, and the Microsoft Graph seems works well for me. Please feel free to let me know if I didn't describe clearly.